# Radio button opens textbox when checked, but won't close it when unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I'm trying to create a dynamic form whereby users can select to either upload and image or embed a youtube clip.

I have tried this using radio inputs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".youtube").change(function () {
    //check if radio button is checked.
    if (this.checked && this.value === "youtube") {
        //show a text box 'embedbode' when radio 'youtube' is checked
        $("#embedcode").show();
    } else if (!this.checked && this.value === "image"){
        //hide the text box when 'image' is checked
        $("#embedcode").hide();
    }

});
</script>
```

And this is the html:

```
<input type="radio" value="image" id="type" name="type" checked='checked' autocomplete="off" />
<label>Image</label>
<input type="radio" value="youtube" id="type" name="type" class="youtube" />
<label>Video</label>
<input id="embedcode" placeholder="embed code" name="embedcode" type="text"/>
```

The radio button `image` is selected by default. When a I click on the video radio button a textbox opens whereby I can input an embed code for the video.
However, when I click back to `image`, should I change my mind on what I want to upload, the embed textbox is still there.
I've looked at the JS and can't see where I'm going wrong.
I tried adjusting the terms and adding an extra `else if` but the textbox won't hide when I click back to image.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#embedcode").hide();
          $("input[name='type']").change(function () {
               if($(this).val() == "youtube")
                    $("#embedcode").show();
               else
                    $("#embedcode").hide();
          });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When they check the other one, and you do (fixed your code here, to be jQuery):

```
 if (!$(this).prop('checked') && $(this).val() === "image")
```

It is now checked... so it won't hide it.  All you need to do is check for the value, since they clicked it and it's a radio, it will always be checked.

```
if ($(this).val() === "image")
```

An easier way to do this would just be:

```
$(".youtube").change(function () {
    $("#embedcode").toggle($(this).val() == "youtube");
});
```

Comment: Use `this.value` and `this.checked` -- it's must faster. `$(this).val()` is pointless when `this.value` can be used.

Comment: I just feel if you are working within a framework, it makes it much cleaner to stay within that framework.  But, different viewpoints I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#embedcode").hide();
    $("input:radio").change(function () {
        if($(this).val() == "youtube")
        {
            $("#embedcode").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#embedcode").hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```